# Node, Express - Index file not calling files correctly

Tags: node.js, express

Hi in my express project, I have my index file where I require different files to startup my application. These require a database connection file, a file for logging stuff using winston and a file for configuring routes.

I use the `require()` statement within express to call these files, and when I run the application(using nodemon), I expect some messages to be logged to the terminal verifying that the files have been called, however no messages occur.

Here is my code:
**index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

require('./startup/logging') ()
require('./startup/db') ()
require('./startup/routes') (app)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => winston.info(`Listening on port: ${port}`))
```

**db.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const winston = require('winston')

module.exports = function() {

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dwg', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then(() => winston.info('Connected to MongoDB...'))
        .catch(err => console.error("Error"))
}
```

**logging.js**:

```
const winston = require('winston');

    module.exports = function() {
      winston.handleExceptions(
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'uncaughtExceptions.log' }));

      process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
        throw ex;
      });

      winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'logfile.log' });
    }
```

**routes.js**:

```
const express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(express.json())
}
```

No database is created when running the application. I can confirm this by looking at mongodb compass. The message that is meant to be printed by `app.listen()` is also not printed to the console. Does anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doing it this way is your app starts before it gets a chance to do rest of work like creating db connection etc. You should start the app only when these tasks are done. something like this

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const logging = require('./startup/logging');
const db = require('./startup/db');
const routes = require('./startup/routes');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, async () => {
  await logging();
  await db();
  await routes();
  // assuming you have winston here.
  winston.info(`Listening on port: ${port}`)
})

Mongo part is defintely async so need await. Check if routes and logging needs await or not.
```

Comment: Hello. The message for the db connection is printed to the console, however no database is actually created. Do you know why? Thank you.

Comment: connect command is not supposed to connect a db. You need to create the db. Collections gets created by itself.